# optimal display of table data using ajax

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I am using ajax within the codeigniter framework to inject data into a pre-defined (off the shelf) table using code like this ...

```
    foreach ($this->results['rawData'] as $item){
            $str.="<tr onclick='document.location ='#'>"; // link to view record

            $str.='<td class="record-company-name"><input type="checkbox"></td>';
            $str.="<td>".$item->companyname."</td>";
            $str.="<td>".$item->city."</td>";
            $str.="<td>".$item->postcode."</td>";

....

            $str.="</tr>";
        }
echo $str;
```

The table also jquery associated with it that offers pagination and sorting of the data by clicking on the table headers. For 1000 rows all is well but for more than this it is slow and for > 5000 I get a browser warning to quit the script. The data does not change much.

The problem is that ALL the data is being injected into the table at once and it is too much for the jquery to handle.

What is the best way to improve this situation by injecting only say 1000 records each time
in conjunction with pagination. Is the CI pagination class together with memcache a good way to go ?

I am sure that this is a common problem. What are the best solutions to this issue ?

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried the codeigniter framework myself but string concatenation (which you are using) is usually bad for performance in most languages. Maybe you should use a different approch like using JQuery templates instead?

Answer (score 0):

So by injecting you mean displaying right? 
Even if it was faster on the back-end, think about the user. You're downloading 5000 rows at once.
How about just downloading what is displayed?

You can use CI's [pagination](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html) for that. As for sorting the data, you can simply use CI's active record class `$this->db->order_by();`
If this works well, then you can AJAX-ify the whole thing if that's still needed.

Hope this helps. Let us know if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider trying jQuery Grid. It should solve this problem and it also offers many more features for tabular data.